# Routes pagination on index method

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have this url that is very long

```
website.local/movies/movies/12?filter=views
```

(Pagination + get parameters )

how i can obtain this url ( remove "movies" )

http://localhost/downloadz/movies/12?filter=views

My Controller

```
public function movies(){
    $data = array();
    // Système de filtrage
    //$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    //$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page'; 
    //$config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
    $get_vars = $this->input->get();

    if(is_array($get_vars)){
        $config[‘suffix’] = '?'.http_build_query($get_vars,'', '&');
    }

    echo $this->input->get('filter');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('films/movies').
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->where('type','movie')->get('sheets')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] =  12;
    $config['num_links'] = 8;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';
    $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Suivant &rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Précédent';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    //$this->input->get('filter', TRUE)
    $data['items'] = $this->db->where('type','movie')->order_by($this->input->get('filter',TRUE), "DESC")->get('sheets',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3))->result();
    $this->load->view('public/general/movies',$data);
}
```

Comment: $config['base_url'] = [base_url].$this->router->class.'/movies'; or add route in route.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your url will be:

http://localhost/movie/movies/12?filter=views

using routes (config/routes.php):

```
$route['mov'] = "movie/movies"
```

now your url will be:

```
http://localhost/mov/12?filter=views
```